# How to use a windows vm on virtualbox gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to run a windows vm in virtualbox and use it as a runner in git lab, following https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/virtualbox.html#use-native-openssh-and-powershell

I installed native open ssh, git for windows and configured the default shell to be pwsh as they request:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "$PSHOME\pwsh.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

however SSH does not work. When I try to ssh to localhost:

```
ssh MACHINE_NAME\username@localhost
```

I get `Permission denied, try again`

when I do this. If I do

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH /v DefaultShell /d C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

then I can ssh into my machine. THe gitlab can also, but then it complains that bash is not a command on power shell:

```
 00:02
bash : The term 'bash' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path 
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bash -l
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bash:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: Process exited with status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

To fix that, I installed WSL and ubuntu on Windows, but then it gives

```
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: Process exited with status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

this is a known problem in ubuntu which is fixed by removing `.bash_logout` but I can't do this to the WSL image. Also, installing WSL shouldn't be the way here, it should work without WSL.

Comment: I'm not clear on one point. The linked docs also say "Add shell pwsh to config.toml". Did you do that as well? It should be trying to run `pwsh` rather than `bash`.

Comment: @Ouroborus yes I did and it had no effect